# Good resource for evaluting AV and anti Malware software?

Tags: windows, security, anti-virus, malware

I am looking for good resources to use to compare the effectiveness of various antivirus/antimalware software solutions. In particular, I am comparing Windows Security Essentials against Symantec Endpoint. Are there good, objective resources available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gartner does reviews failrly often that may assist you.  This is a start.  [AV Comapratives](http://www.av-comparatives.org/)  claim to be an impartial testing group as well. Each case will be different so if you want the ability to deploy remotely, have ability to have a managemnt server fail or central management that would have an impact on your choice.

I can say that several users I work with used Security Essentials and were infected but when they copied a file to work system, Symantec Endpoint 11 detected and deleted malware.  However, I have no way of knowing if the version they had was current or even fully functional.

Symantec Endpoint has worked well in our environmnet as it is easily managed and updates can be deployed from GUPs at remote offices.

Security Essentials has worked well for a number of users.